# PHP and MySql, Login Query

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, project

I am facing some problems in Login page of my final year project;

My problem statement:

1. I have created login form and also connected with the database, when I Add record into the database,
   Record successfully added, but there is a problem in login form. when i enter username and password, the record does not fetched from the database by using login form.

   On the other hand i have checked only single user login authentication. (using Sql Query) Then i have successfully logged In.
2. I have make primary key as a user_id,
   I have created  two variables for this purpose,
   When I use calling function, then the result failed, means  *else* part Printed on the screen.

$username,
&password,

Variables which i have created, but do not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the source code? It would be helpful.